# Как подсчитать уровни поддержки\сопротивления на свечном графике программно

Tags: python, c#

Хочу высчитывать уровни поддержки\сопротивления на C# для свечного графика, но так и не нашел готового решения на C# (если они есть, просьба поделиться), а пока пытаюсь переделать код из питона на C#.
Вот статься с которой брал информацию:

[Статья](https://towardsdatascience.com/detection-of-price-support-and-resistance-levels-in-python-baedc44c34c9)

[Код из статьи на GitHub](https://github.com/gianlucamalato/machinelearning/blob/master/Support_and_resistance.ipynb)

Первую часть я реализовал

```
using CalculateSupportsAndResistances;
using Signals.DataAccess;

var dbConnection = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\INFO\sqlLocalDbConnection.txt");

var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

using var db = await new DbAdapterConnection(dbConnection).OpenAsync(cancellationToken);

var myCandles = await db.ExecuteReaderAsync<MyCandle>(
    cancellationToken
    , @"
SELECT
    [Id]
    ,[CandleVolume] as [Volume]
    ,[CandleOpen] as [Open]
    ,[CandleHigh] as [High]
    ,[CandleLow] as [Low]
    ,[CandleClose] as [Close]
    ,[CandleDateTime] as [Date]
FROM [Test].[CandleData]
order by CandleDateTime desc
");

var myCandlesArray = myCandles.ToArray();

var linePoints = new List<LinePoint>();

for (var i = 2; i < myCandlesArray.Length - 2; i++)
{
    var item = myCandlesArray[i];

    if (IsSupport(myCandlesArray, i))
    {
        linePoints.Add(new LinePoint(
            item.Id
            , item.Date
            , item.Low
            , 2)
        );
    }
    else if (IsResistance(myCandlesArray, i))
    {
        linePoints.Add(new LinePoint(
            item.Id
            , item.Date
            , item.High
            , 1)
        );
    }
}

foreach (var linePoint in linePoints)
{
    Console.WriteLine(linePoint.Point);
}

Console.ReadKey();

static bool IsSupport(IReadOnlyList<MyCandle> myCandlesArray, int i)
{
    var result = myCandlesArray[i].Low < myCandlesArray[i - 1].Low
                 && myCandlesArray[i].Low < myCandlesArray[i + 1].Low
                 && myCandlesArray[i + 1].Low < myCandlesArray[i + 2].Low
                 && myCandlesArray[i - 1].Low < myCandlesArray[i - 2].Low;

    return result;
}

static bool IsResistance(IReadOnlyList<MyCandle> myCandlesArray, int i)
{
    var result = myCandlesArray[i].High > myCandlesArray[i - 1].High
                 && myCandlesArray[i].High > myCandlesArray[i + 1].High
                 && myCandlesArray[i+1].High > myCandlesArray[i + 2].High
                 && myCandlesArray[i-1].High > myCandlesArray[i - 2].High;

    return result;
}
```

А с второй проблемы (часть где убираем шумы).
На сколько я понял

```
s =  np.mean(df['High'] - df['Low'])
```

это среднее значение суммы всех элементов High-Low (если ошибся поправьте).
Т.е. что-то типа этого

```
decimal arraySumm = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < myCandlesArray.Length; i++)
{
    var currentCandle = myCandlesArray[i];
    var middle = currentCandle.High - currentCandle.Low;
    arraySumm += middle;
}

var s = arraySumm / myCandlesArray.Length;
```

А вот эту функцию так и не смог понять

```
def isFarFromLevel(l):
  return np.sum([abs(l-x) < s  for x in levels]) == 0
```

Помогите пожалуйста ее переделать в C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def isFarFromLevel(l):
  return np.sum([abs(l-x) < s  for x in levels]) == 0
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ = 1 если True, = 0 если False
```

Тут используется один из трюков питона, состоящий в том, что булевы значения можно использовать в числовой арифметике. Фактически здесь проверяется, что в массиве `levels` нет ни одного такого значения `x`, что выполняется неравенство `abs(l-x) < s`. Т.е. в `levels` все значения лежат от `l` дальше, чем величина `s`. Собственно, название функции в переводе про это и говорит - "находятся далеко от уровня".

Можно и наоборот записать: для всех `x` из массива `levels` должно выполняться неравенство `abs(l-x) >= s`. Теперь я думаю вы сможете записать это на `C#`: просто делаете перебор элементов массива и проверяете условие, если условие не выполняется, то сразу делаете `return false`, а в конце функции делаете `return true`, если прошли весь цикл и условие ни разу не нарушилось.

И про `s = np.mean(df['High'] - df['Low'])` вы правильно догадались, `mean` - это "среднее арифметическое".

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Я вот что-то подобное думал, но np.sum() сбивало с толка, вроде бы sum считает сумму элементов в массиве, но внутри скобок булевое значение